# How to Enable Runtime Code Changes and Move Execution Pointer in Blazor WASM Client-Side Debugging with Mono/C#?

Tags: debugging, mono, visual-studio-2022, .net-5, webassembly

I'm currently working on a Blazor WebAssembly (WASM) .NET5 application and facing a challenge with client-side debugging: I'm looking to enable runtime code changes and move the execution pointer, similar to what's possible when debugging server-side. My development environment is Visual Studio 2022, and I'm using Mono/C# for the client-side part.

So far, I've noticed that these advanced debugging features don't seem to be directly available for client-side debugging. While server-side debugging works smoothly, allowing me to make changes that are automatically applied and to move the execution pointer, I can't find comparable options for client-side debugging.

Are there specific settings, extensions, or tools I need to enable to facilitate this kind of advanced debugging for Blazor WASM on the client side? Are particular versions of .NET or Mono required to support such debugging features?

Any tips or guidance on how to enable these debugging capabilities would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

I have made several attempts to improve client-side debugging for my Blazor WASM application in Visual Studio 2022:

Researching Documentation and Online Resources: I scoured Microsoft's official documentation and various online forums for any hints on advanced debugging features that enable runtime code changes and moving the execution pointer on the client side.

Tweaking VS2022 Settings: I adjusted different settings within Visual Studio 2022, hoping to uncover hidden or undocumented options for enhanced debugging.

Checking for Updates: I ensured that my .NET and Mono versions were up to date to rule out any compatibility issues.

My expectation was to find a way to make the client-side debugging experience as robust as the server-side. Specifically, I was hoping for:

Runtime Code Changes: The ability to modify code at runtime and see those changes reflected immediately in the running application without needing to restart the debugging session.

Moving the Execution Pointer: The capability to freely move the execution pointer to manually test different execution paths without having to rerun the entire code.

Despite my efforts, I was unable to activate or find such functionality, leading to an inefficient debugging experience, particularly when it comes to testing and refining the client side.

Answer (score 0):

If you continue on .NET 5, I think what you expected is unachievable.

Take a look of this:

[Hot Load Support for .NET applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/hot-reload?view=vs-2022#support-for-net-applications)

[image]

I think you need .NET6  at least.